# How to make sure that the format of a heading is not lost after adding a heading style and the heading numbering is retained in table of content?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, styles, table-of-contents

My paper is structured like this:

```
1.  Introduction
2.  Conceptual background
2.1.    Definition
2.2.    Delineate the Boundaries of the Research
2.3.    Research Streams
2.4.    Theoretical Background
...
```

I would like to add an automated table of content for these sections. However, when I add the heading style as demonstrated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285059/how-to-create-a-table-of-contents-by-marking-text-in-word), the font is always changed and the numbering will be lost. I don't know how to retain the format of the headings adding heading style. I tried customizing the style, but I cannot find anything about the color of the font and the numbering.

I want the table of content to be numbered on the gradation principle as well.

I use Microsoft Word 2007 on a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you review the Shauna Kelly pages for the straight scoop on Multilevel lists (your section headings) and on creating a TOC. Microsoft may own the software, but their documentation and explanations aren't so hot.

Shauna's pages are well written. I'm sure aft reading the section on multilevel lists and TOCs that you'll never again have a problem using them.

[Shauna Kelly's Word Pages](https://shaunakelly.com/topic/word/numbering.html)